# Intent Service for push notifications in android from SignalR

Tags: android-service, intentservice

I am using SignalR to send notifications to my android client. For this, I am using Intent Service. The problem is that when I swipe out the app from recent apps, the service gets stopped. It is happening because IntentService is not running all the time but it works on Intent base.

Basically, I want to know whether I should use a Regular Service to receive notification constantly or is there any other way to keep intent service alive to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntentService is designed to do a piece of work then shut down, so can not use intent service for that.

For your task, you need to make service sticky return START_STICKY onStartCommand of the service. and in the doc, it's mentioned if the process is killed system will recreate again

> if this service's process is killed while it is started (after
>   returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the
>   started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system
>   will try to re-create the service. Because it is in the started state,
>   it will guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after
>   creating the new service instance; if there are not any pending start
>   commands to be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null
>   the intent object, so you must take care to check for this.